# How to bring up new window for each selection from checkbox list in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm new, building a practice project in C# and ASP.NET. Have a checkbox list with 7 insurance products; when a user selects a product, I need to bring up a new window where they can customize this product. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a new window, you need client-side javascript ([window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)).
**EDIT**
in response to the submit of the list, generate some script statements (see [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)).

But are you really sure that this is what you want: open a handful of new windows?
A different approach would be to remember that list server-side (in Session) and handle those products one-by-one.
**EDIT**
You could have a redirect page: as long as there are items in the list, take&remove the first one and show the page for that. When that page is finished, redirect back yo the redirect page. When the list is done, go back to the list (or whatever).

Comment: I've got the javascript (although it's not quite working for me

` <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" oncheckedchanged="javascript: Pub()" Text="Public D&amp;O" />` 

throws a compilation error, no idea why). Yes, session-saving the selections does sound cleaner, but I was daunted by the code for it. Would that necessitate a switch-case, an if-then, or what? (Thanks, btw.)

Comment: @Brazos - I extended my answer.